# use template function to cast between multiple class types safely

Tags: c++

A third-party library I'm using requires that pointers be passed as a `void*`. At any given time this pointer may need to be cast to one of several classes in the inheritance chain. This fails when multiple inheritance is involved, so my devised method to make this happen safely is to propagate the class type along with the pointer in order to properly cast to the desired type. The following demonstrates the intended goal:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdio.h>

enum class kTypeFlag { PARENTONE, PARENTTWO, CHILD };

#define CAST_TO_CLASS_TYPE(TO, FROM, POINTER)                            \
  dynamic_cast<TO*>(static_cast<FROM*>(POINTER))

class ParentOne {
 public:
  ParentOne() { }
  virtual ~ParentOne() { }
  virtual size_t byte_size() const = 0;
};

class ParentTwo {
 public:
  ParentTwo(uint32_t id) : id_(id) { }
  virtual ~ParentTwo() { }
  uint32_t id() const { return id_; }
 private:
  const uint32_t id_;
};

class Child : public ParentOne, public ParentTwo {
 public:
  Child(uint32_t id) : ParentOne(), ParentTwo(id) { }
  virtual ~Child() { }
  size_t byte_size() const override { return sizeof(*this); }
};

template <class T>
T* Convert(void* pointer, kTypeFlag flag) {
  switch (flag) {
    case kTypeFlag::PARENTONE:
      return CAST_TO_CLASS_TYPE(T, ParentOne, pointer);
    case kTypeFlag::PARENTTWO:
      return CAST_TO_CLASS_TYPE(T, ParentTwo, pointer);
    case kTypeFlag::CHILD:
      return CAST_TO_CLASS_TYPE(T, Child, pointer);
    default:
      assert(0 && "invalid flag to Convert");
  }
}

int main() {
  Child* child = new Child(5);
  printf("byte_size: %zu\n", child->byte_size());
  printf("id: %u\n", child->id());

  ParentOne* p1 = Convert<ParentOne>(child, kTypeFlag::CHILD);
  ParentTwo* p2 = Convert<ParentTwo>(child, kTypeFlag::CHILD);
  printf("byte_size: %zu\n", p1->byte_size());
  printf("id: %u\n", p2->id());
}
```

Note that `CAST_TO_CLASS_TYPE` uses a `dynamic_cast` instead of a `static_cast`. This is because if a `static_cast` is used the build fails with:

```
run.cc:40:14: error: static_cast from 'ParentTwo *' to 'ParentOne *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed
      return CAST_TO_CLASS_TYPE(T, ParentTwo, pointer);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
run.cc:9:3: note: expanded from macro 'CAST_TO_CLASS_TYPE'
  static_cast<TO*>(static_cast<FROM*>(POINTER))
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
run.cc:53:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Convert<ParentOne>' requested here
  ParentOne* p1 = Convert<ParentOne>(child, kTypeFlag::CHILD);
                  ^
```

So my questions are: Why does the build fail when using `static_cast`? Or is there a different way to do this completely? The end goal is to enforce some type safety around needing to cast a `void*` to several different types. I'm not concerned about how this is done. The above is simply the best I could come up with.

**EDIT**: Allow me to clarify why using `dynamic_cast` isn't ideal. The following snippet compiles fine:

```
ParentTwo* p2 = new ParentTwo(42);
ParentOne* p1 = Convert<ParentOne>(p2, kTypeFlag::PARENTTWO);
printf("id: %u\n", p2->id());
printf("byte_size: %zu\n", p1->byte_size());
```

But it aborts at runtime. Preferably this would be caught at compile time. Which is why I'd like to use a `static_cast`, but isn't possible because of the reason explained above.

Comment: Why are you overcomplicating the things. Why not simply use `ParentOne* p1 = child`?

Comment: Your program looks perfectly OK to me. What compiler and flags are you using?

Comment: @MohitJain That code is simply for demonstration. When being used `child` will have been assigned to a `void*`, where I may want access to the parent class only.

Comment: The compiler says it in very clear and simple language. "static_cast from 'ParentTwo *' to 'ParentOne *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed". What is your question exactly?

Comment: @n.m. Observe the usage in `main()`. At no time am I attempting to cast from `ParentTwo*` to `ParentOne*`. It's casting from `Child*` to both. If I comment out those lines then the program compiles fine. In this is my question.

Comment: The forbidden cast is in the case branch that is not being executed. Doesn't mean you can write arbitrary incirrect code in it.

Comment: You seem to think that just because the code in the switch shouldn't be *called* in a given condition, it should none-the-less compile. That isn't the case. The compiler has no way of knowing what condition it will be called under, and must try to prepare for what you're asking (and it can't).

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh duh. Now that you say it, seems so obvious. The end goal is to prevent compile IIF user code is invalid. There a way you can think of to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got an explanation of why your code doesn't work in the comments. You seem to want an alternative, so here it is.

http://ideone.com/24iaNv

```
namespace details
{
    template<typename To, kTypeFlag>
    struct cex {To* operator()() { static_assert(!std::is_same<To, To>::value, "invalid flag to Convert");} };
    template<typename To>
    struct cex<To, kTypeFlag::PARENTONE> { To* operator()(void*p) { return static_cast<To*>(static_cast<ParentOne*>(p)); } };
    template<typename To>
    struct cex<To, kTypeFlag::PARENTTWO> { To* operator()(void*p) { return static_cast<To*>(static_cast<ParentTwo*>(p)); } };
    template<typename To>
    struct cex<To, kTypeFlag::CHILD>     { To* operator()(void*p) { return static_cast<To*>(static_cast<Child*>(p)); } };
};

template <typename T, kTypeFlag f>
T* ConvertEx (void* pointer) { return details::cex<T, f>()(pointer); }
```

Comment: Most excellent. This produces the exact results I was hoping for.

Comment: To allow `static_assert`, you have to make the condition dependent of template parameter, as replacing `false` by `!std::is_same<T, T>::value`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, I don't use GCC so I had no idea. Do you happen to know who's right here, visual studio, or GCC?

Comment: gcc is right, msvc doesn't do the required 2 passes.

Comment: If `kTypeFlag` argument can be a compile time constant, the `To` part might be removed (computed) BTW.